# C# If, Else If Odd Error

Tags: c#

I am creating an inventory program for C#, and so far I have scripted a function to print out all items in my inventory, and now I am creating a function to get more info about an item.  When I print out my inventory, it just prints the name of my item.  This function will print all the details, so such that if it was a weapon, it would print the name, damage, and critical hit of it.

So here is my GetInfo Function:

```
  public void GetInfo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("If you want more detail about an item, type the number to its left.  \nOtherwise, type (Q)");

    int getinfo;
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out getinfo);
    getinfo -= 1; 

    if(getinfo > InventorySlots || getinfo < 0)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("You entered an invalid number"); 
    }

    if (weapons.Count >= getinfo)
    {
        Console.Clear(); 
        Console.Write("Weapon Name: " + weapons[getinfo].name + "\nDamage: " + weapons[getinfo].damage + "\nCritical: " + weapons[getinfo].critical);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    else if ((weapons.Count + armors.Count) >= getinfo)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Armor Name: " + armors[getinfo].name + "\nArmor Value: " + armors[getinfo].armor + "\nHealth Boost: " + armors[getinfo].healthboost);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    else if ((weapons.Count + armors.Count + ores.Count) >= getinfo)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Ore Name" + ores[getinfo].name + "(" + ores[getinfo].stack + ")"); 
    }

}
```

Now, the issue is that the statement:

```
if(weapons.Count >= getinfo
```

is executing even though getinfo is larger than weapons.Count.  Why would the statement execute if the statement is invalid?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is it throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? Printing out the statement when you don't expect it to?

Comment: So, what's the value of `weapons.Count` and the input from `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: The reason I have the statement getinfo -= 1 at the beginning is the list begins at 0.  The number next to the item starts at 1), then 2), so if they type 1, they actually mean 0 in the list, so I have to subtract 1 to get the equivalent list number.

Comment: weapons.Count, armors.Count, and ores.Count all currently have one value stored in each so I could make sure everything was working the way it should.  The item menu looks like this:                                                                                                                                   1) Steel Sword \n2) Steel Armor \n3) Bronze Ore.  So Console.ReadLine() is reading 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the issue is that the statement ... is executing even though getinfo is larger than weapons.Count.

Presumably you're saying this because you're getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the code hits this:

```
weapons[getinfo].name
```

So you're assuming `getinfo` is greater than `weapons.Count`. But in truth it's *equal to* `weapons.Count`. In C#, index accesses to lists and arrays are zero-based, which means that `weapons[weapons.Count - 1]` is the last item in that collection.

Change your `if` statement to:

```
if (weapons.Count > getinfo)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did that plus a few other edits and it works great!

Comment: @user2097371: I'm glad. Be sure to mark the answer correct so that people don't think your question still needs answering.